# How to setup two USRPs B210 in GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am trying to setup two USRP B210 with external Octoclock in GNU Radio in order to achieve 4 RX channels.

What is the right way?

1.One USRP source with Num Mboards = 2, and Num Channels = 4.

or

2.Two USRP source, each with Num Mbords = 1, and Num Channels = 2.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.One USRP source with Num Mboards = 2, and Num Channels = 4.

Probably can't do that, UHD's `multi_usrp` doesn't deal with multiple b2xx devices, so only your other option

> 2.Two USRP source, each with Num Mbords = 1, and Num Channels = 2.

works.