# Are the 4 Rx channels, organized by two B210s, synchronous?

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I would like to develop my question posted here:
[How to setup two USRPs B210 in GNU Radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901328/how-to-setup-two-usrps-b210-in-gnu-radio).
Based on comment, now I have following flowgraph:
[image]
I have two B210s, that share common clock and PPS via external Octoclock.
The two channels of each B210 are synchronous.
What is relationship of channels of different B210s?
Could I assume synchronism between them too?

Comment: Could you describe what kind of synchronicity you mean? because frequency-wise, yes, they are.

Comment: I mean time-synchronous.
Is channel 1 of USRP 1 time aligned with channel 1 of  USRP 2?

Comment: No; https://kb.ettus.com/Synchronizing_USRP_Events_Using_Timed_Commands_in_UHD

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not in themselves synchronous.

You need to do the following:

1. Connect a common pulse source (Pulse per Second, PPS) to the USRP's PPS input
2. set that as source for timing,
3. set the time at a PPS edge to the same time on both devices
4. **only** use timed commands to start and stop the streams

Comment: For points 1 and 2:
I use Octclock and two radios are configured clock and time source - external and the sync - unknown PPS. I assume points 1 and 2 fulfilled.
Points 3 and 4: Is it achieved via appropriate configuration of USRP source block in GRC or I have to change manualy grc file, or write custom program? Are there single reference that explains points 3 and 4. I know the refference you pointed out in your previous comment, but for point 3 there is written "We won't cover it much in this application note". Could you ellaborate little bit more points 3 and 4.

Comment: re point 3&4: "python snippets" in modern GNU Radio Companion" is a way to insert Python code at desired points.